# Problems with alloc and facebook init

Tags: ios, facebook, cocos2d-iphone

I have a singleton class that i use to handle all the facebook stuff...

but when i try to init the _facebook it throws an unrecognizer selector exception

- (id)initWithAppId:(NSString *)appId andDelegate:(id)delegate;

this is the init method i'm using...

```
 -(void) login {
    // Check if there is a valid session.
    @try {
         _facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId andDelegate:self];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
         NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n, %@", exception.name, exception.reason]);
    }
    @finally {

    }

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
         && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
         _facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
         _facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }
    if (![_facebook isSessionValid]) {
         [_facebook authorize:_permissions];
    }else{
         [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
    }

 }
```

Comment: this is the exception i get. NSInvalidArgumentException
, -[Facebook initWithAppId:andDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaacb0a0

Comment: It seems that there is no problem for your code. Have you try to init the facebook in other class?

Comment: Yeah I did.. I've tried initializing the facebook in AppDelegate. But still got the same exception

Comment: How about running the sample code from facebook ios sdk example? Make sure you have follow the steps in this doc:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

Comment: the hackbook example works... dont have any idea my doesn't

Comment: Make sure to add all the classes needed into your project and import them inside your class

Comment: I've managed it to work, facebook's sdk it's buggy, i've created an new init method in facebook.m that just calls the other init, now it works flawslely

Answer (score 1):

Try product -> clean. You have probably copied and replaced the Facebook source files outside XCode.